# unary operator expected with more than 1 argument

Tags: shell, unix

```
for var in "$@"
do
 if test -z $var
   then
    echo "missing operand"
 elif [ -d $var ]
   then
    echo "This is a directory"
 elif [ ! -f  $var ]
   then
    echo "The file does not exist"
 else
   basename=$(basename $var)
   dirname=$(readlink -f $var)
   inodeno=$(ls -i $var| cut -d" " -f1)
   read -p "remove regular file $@" input
   if [ $input = "n" ]
   then exit 1
   fi

   mv $var "$var"_"$inodeno"
   echo "$basename"_"$inodeno":"$dirname" >> $HOME/.restore.info
   mv "$var"_"$inodeno"  $HOME/deleted
 fi


done
```

**Hello, the above code is trying to mimic the rm command in unix. Its purpose is to remove the file .
Eg if I type in bash safe_rm file1 , it works however if  type in 
bash safe_rm file1 file 2 , it prompts me to remove file 1 twice and gives me a unary operater expected  for line 27(if [ $input = "n" ]).
Why does it not work for two files, ideally I would like it to prompt me to remove file1 and file 2. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "remove regular file $@" input
```

should probably be

```
read -p "remove regular file $var" input
```

That's the basic.

And this is how I'd prefer to do it:

```
for T in "$@"; do
    if [[ -z $T ]]; then
        echo "Target is null."
    elif [[ ! -e $T ]]; then
        echo "Target does not exist: $T"
    elif [[ -d $T ]]; then
        echo "Target can't be a directory: $T"
    else
        BASE=${T##*/}
        DIRNAME=$(exec dirname "$T")  ## Could be simpler but not sure how you want to use it.
        INODE_NUM=$(exec stat -c '%i' "$T")
        read -p "Remove regular file $T? "
        if [[ $REPLY == [yY] ]]; then
            # Just copied. Not sure about its logic.
            mv "$T" "${T}_${INODE_NUM}"
            echo "${BASE}_${INODE_NUM}:${DIRNAME}" >> "$HOME/.restore.info"
            mv "${T}_${INODE_NUM}" "$HOME/deleted"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank you very much, your method worked. But can you please tell me why my method didnt work, I am very new to unix.

Comment: @user3809938 $@ expands to all the arguments passed to your function or script i.e. it represents $1, $2, $3 and so on..

Comment: @user3809938 A quick way to learn bash scripting is to read [Bash Beginner's Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and always refer to the [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) (`man bash`) for everything. `help` is also a good quick reference. P.S. I assumed you use Bash because of the way you use `-p` argument to `read`. Also remember that `bash` != `sh`. Don't confuse the two to be the same.